# Django views 'else' syntax error

Tags: python, django, syntax, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 functions in my django views.py file, which are giving me problems. Django is showing that there is a syntax error at the else lines, but I can't see any problem near it.(All required functions etc are imported) 
I would like some help with this

```
@login_required         
def add_post(request, forumslug, threadslug):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            body = form.closed_data['body']
            thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, slug=threadslug)
            forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, slug=forumslug)
            post = Post.objects.create(title=title, body=body, creator=user, thread=thread)
            url = '/%s/%s/' % (forumslug, slugify(title))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
        return render_to_response('forum/new_post.html', variables)


@login_required    
def add_thread(request, forumslug):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, slug=forumslug)
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            thread = Thread.objects.create(title=title, slug=slugify(title), forum=forum, creator=user, body=body)
            url = '/%s/%s' % (forumslug, slugify(title))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        variables = RequestConext(request, {'form': form})
        return render_to_response('forum/new_thread.html', variables)
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? On a somewhat unrelated note, I'm wondering what would happen if an invalid form was submitted, since in that case it seems you wouldn't return an `HttpResponse` object--which seems like something Django would (and should) complain about.

Comment: As this is just the beginning, I haven't done anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `url = '/%s/%s/' % (forumslug, slugify(title)` is actually missing a closing bracket, sure the error is not raised for the line that is above the `else` one?

Comment: Hmm.... that was a copy paste error...but there is still a problem. Edit: Actually that did solve the problem, thanks! Though I have a new problem now, which  I have to solve.

Comment: @Yogesh When you encounter a *syntax error*, please double check your copy&past. There are no SyntaxError in the revised code - Might want to tell us what the syntax error message is?

Comment: @YogeshAgarwal Do you get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` or do you have anything else?

Comment: Its something else, which was easily fixed. Thanks